# loop jQuery simple animated lines 3 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Update:** Due to vagueness of my question - resulted in a broad answer that doesn't really apply (as you can see below). My full question and problem migrated to -- > [add a loop function around 3 small animations within larger animation functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629254/add-a-loop-function-around-3-small-animations-within-larger-animation-functions)

---

How to define the below to loop / play specifically 3 times in a row before stopping (simple line animation with jQuery):

My animation works.. it's basically three lines that come out one at a time that draw a triangle... It's the looping 3 times i need.

```
    var padding = $('.conn-1').css('padding');
    var line_anim = 700;
    $('.replay').hide();
    $('.conn-1').width('100%').animate({'height':'100%'},line_anim,
    function () {
        $('.conn-2').height('100%').animate({'width':'100%'}, line_anim,
            function () {
                $('.conn-3').css({width:'100%'}).animate({'height':'100%'}, line_anim,
                         function(){replay();})
            }
        );
    }
    );
    //$('.conn-2').width(0).siblings('.connect-lines').css('margin',0);
    }, 2000);    
    });
    },5000);

    }
```

Updated code via answered suggestions -- the below didn't run / work with the looping; any additional thoughts?

```
                                      function animAll(remainingLoops){
                                      if(!remainingLoops) return;
                                    $('.replay').hide();
                                    $('.conn-1').width('100%').animate({'height':'100%'},line_anim, function () {
                                    $('.conn-2').height('100%').animate({'width':'100%'}, line_anim, function () {
                                    $('.conn-3').css({width:'100%'}).animate({'height':'100%'}, line_anim, function(){
                                               animAll(remainingLoops-1);
                                               // replay();})
                                                     });
                                                  });
                                                }
                                            );
                                        }
                                    );
                                    //$('.conn-2').width(0).siblings('.connect-lines').css('margin',0);
                                }, 2000);    
                            });
    },5000);

}
```

Comment: Please complete your piece of code, we're missing closing tags.

Comment: @AndreLehnert It's duration.

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // your animation code };`?

Comment: [is this what you're trying to achieve?](http://jsfiddle.net/L6e5zky9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function animAll(remainingLoops){
    if(!remainingLoops) return;
    $('#blue').width(50).animate({width: '100%'}, function(){
        $('#red').width(50).animate({width: '100%'}, function(){
            $('#green').width(50).animate({width: '100%'}, function(){
                animAll(remainingLoops-1);
            });
        });
    });
}

animAll(3);
```

```css
div{height:50px;background:#00f}#red{background:red}#green{background:green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
```