# add a loop function around 3 small animations within larger animation functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Below is the entire animation function.

I have a smaller animation within this. It is basically these 3 lines of code below (which draws a triangle). I simply want the below to execute 3 times.

```
$('.conn-1').width('100%').animate({'height':'100%'},line_anim, function () {
$('.conn-2').height('100%').animate({'width':'100%'}, line_anim, function () {
$('.conn-3').css({width:'100%'}).animate({'height':'100%'}, line_anim,
```

**Full JS animation function below:** I have added '`// comments`' of where my recent attempt is. Basically trying to wrap a function that loops 3 times as a variable around these lines, if you look at full code toward the bottom you'll see. not sure if it's broken because of syntax due to how many functions are involved / nested.

```
   function enterprise() {
       $('.medical-center .icon-1').addClass('caro-anim');
       //caro_icon();
       $('.conn').height(0).width(0);
        setTimeout(function(){
            medical_array.length = 0;
            uni_array.length = 0;
            children_array.length = 0;
                    var scale_time =3000;
                    $('.replay').hide();
                    $('.medical-text').addClass('scale-anim');
                    $('.medical-center').addClass('scale-anim').animate({margin: '-26% 0px -34%'}, scale_time,
                            function(){$(this).hide().show()}).siblings('.ferris').delay(scale_time/2).animate({opacity:1},scale_time/2,
                                function(){/* $('.connect-lines').animate({opacity:1},scale_time/2); */
                                    setTimeout(function(){
                                        pushArray(medical_array, '.medical-center');
                                        pushArrysa(uni_array,'.university-hospital');
                                        pushArray(children_array,'.childrens-hospital');
                                        var padding = $('.conn-1').css('padding');
                                        var line_anim = 700;
                                        $('.replay').hide();
                                        function animAll(remainingLoops){ // recent attempt
                                        if(!remainingLoops) return; // recent attempt
                                        $('.conn-1').width('100%').animate({'height':'100%'},line_anim,
                                            function () {
                                        $('.conn-2').height('100%').animate({'width':'100%'}, line_anim,
                                            function () {
                                        $('.conn-3').css({width:'100%'}).animate({'height':'100%'}, line_anim,
                                            function(){replay();
                                                        animAll(remainingLoops-1); // recent attempt
                                                            }); // recent attempt
                                                          }); // recent attempt
                                                       });
                                                     }
                                                     animAll(3); // recent attempt
                                                  );
                                                }
                                              );
                                        //$('.conn-2').width(0).siblings('.connect-lines').css('margin',0);
                                         }, 2000);    
                                    });
                                 },5000);
                             }
```

Recent attempt stand alone below.. But I think the nested functions or immediate amount of may be resulting in a syntax issue, within full code above.

```
   function animAll(remainingLoops){ // recent attempt
                                if(!remainingLoops) return; // recent attempt
                                $('.conn-1').width('100%').animate({'height':'100%'},line_anim,
                                    function () {
                                $('.conn-2').height('100%').animate({'width':'100%'}, line_anim,
                                    function () {
                                $('.conn-3').css({width:'100%'}).animate({'height':'100%'}, line_anim,
                                    function(){replay();
                                                animAll(remainingLoops-1); // recent attempt
                                                    }); // recent attempt
                                                  }); // recent attempt
                                               });
                                             }
                                             animAll(3); // recent attempt
```

Comment: where is replay() defined? you also have a syntax error at :pushArrysa

Comment: replay works.. the issue is not replay; the issue is the LOOP.

Comment: Even minus that syntax error it still doesn't work...

Comment: i mean could you post replay(), i'm trying to be helpful but just saying the loop isn't working isn't really helpful. what about the loop isn't working? I can't run the code so at best its going to be a what i can view, mainly syntax errors and obvious logic flaws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting shouldn't cause errors if done right. It's really hard to read your code, but i'm going to guess its something related to the way the code is not properly formatted because there were some weird places where the timeout times were not with the setTimeout. Also, in your animation, it sets the width: 100%, etc. but it never set its back to the initial value. jQuery Animate doesn't reset the variables which is why it only seems like its running once, unless replay() is resetting it... which is why I was asking for the replay() code, I can't figure out anything from what is shown what the problem is....

```
function enterprise() {
     $('.medical-center .icon-1').addClass('caro-anim');

     $('.conn').height(0).width(0);

     setTimeout(function () {
         medical_array.length = 0;
         uni_array.length = 0;
         children_array.length = 0;

         var scale_time = 3000;

         $('.replay').hide();
         $('.medical-text').addClass('scale-anim');

         $('.medical-center').addClass('scale-anim').animate({
             margin: '-26% 0px -34%'
         }, scale_time,

         function () {
             $(this).hide().show()
         }).siblings('.ferris').delay(scale_time / 2).animate({
             opacity: 1
         }, scale_time / 2,

         function () {
             setTimeout(function () {
                 pushArray(medical_array, '.medical-center');
                 pushArray(uni_array, '.university-hospital');
                 pushArray(children_array, '.childrens-hospital');
                 var padding = $('.conn-1').css('padding');
                 var line_anim = 700;
                 $('.replay').hide();

                 animAll(3);

                 function animAll(remainingLoops) {
                     if (!remainingLoops) return; 
                     $('.conn-1').width('100%').animate({
                         'height': '100%'
                     }, line_anim,

                     function () {
                         $('.conn-2').height('100%').animate({
                             'width': '100%'
                         }, line_anim,

                         function () {
                             $('.conn-3').css({
                                 width: '100%'
                             }).animate({
                                 'height': '100%'
                             }, line_anim,

                             function () {
                                 replay();
                                 //reset all the .conn-* classes here
                                 //call the animAll again
                                 animAll(remainingLoops - 1);
                             });
                         }); 
                     });
                 }

             }, 2000);
         });

     }, 5000);
};
```

is what it should look like after proper formatting

Comment: thanks, but it still doesn't loop. any ideas on how to reset jQuery animate?

Comment: @LoydChristmas the easiest way is set all the properties back to intial values (whatever they were) right before doing another animAll() call or at the beginning of the function